# Using mapviz gpsfix vs navsatfix

Tags: gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Mapviz apparently uses GPSFix.It seems like most GPS nodes are still using NavSatFix which is a subset of the items in GPSFix.

- Is there a mapping node between these two message types for Indigo?
- In general is everything moving to GPSFix over NavSatFix?
- Does mapviz somehow support NavSatFix in Indigo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220368/using-mapviz-gpsfix-vs-navsatfix/) by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2015-11-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe Mapviz already supports NavSatFix. Try to compile the most recent version of Mapviz from Source, just to make sure.

If somebody still needs to convert NavSatFix messages to GPSFix (or the other way round), you can use the fix_translator script from the **gps_common** package (see http://wiki.ros.org/gps_common):

```
roslaunch gps_common fix_translator.launch
```

You need to adapt fix_translator.launch to the topic names on your system.

---

Originally posted by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) with karma: 775 on 2017-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0